# C# .net integral constant in html actionlink is too large

Tags: c#, html, actionlink

I currently am trying to pass a value to a controller action and the integer i am trying to pass is too long. To overcome this, I have tried using `new { trackingNumber = 9374869903500896631228d }` and changing the parameter type of my action to a double but then the value is passed in as `9.3748699035009E+21` instead of `937486990350089663128`. How can I change the below Html.ActionLink and controller action so that I can pass the value `937486990350089663128`to my action?

Action Link:

`<div>@Html.ActionLink("Track Package", "TrackPackage", "Orders", new { trackingNumber = 9374869903500896631228 }, null)</div>`

Controller Action:

`public void TrackPackage(int trackingNumber) {
     // .....do stuff with trackingNumber
}`

Comment: What about the long data type instad of int? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx Or just parse it as a string?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen not enough digits in long to represent this number as far as I can tell?

Comment: why not treat it as a string internally?

Comment: Then just do it as a string

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple type in c# that can hold a integral number that big (`long` resp. `Int64` only have about 18 digits). And `double`, although it has the range for such a big number, lacks the precision. So you can only pass the value as a `string`. If you need arithmetic operations on the number on the server side, you can use the `BigInteger` structure. You can convert the string into a BigInteger using the `Parse` method.

```
public void TrackPage(string trackingnumber) {
    BigInteger tracker = BigInteger.Parse(trackingnumber);   
    // do something with your number 
}
```